# Return to NSArray matching cross criteria

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to return objects to an NSArray when they match 1 or more criteria (kOption).
The code I came out with works well if I have kOption1 OR kOption2 OR kOption3 and so on, but if I have kOption1 AND KOption2 it will just return the first.

I just started programming and I'm trying to figure out how to get ou of this without having to write tons of if/else nested condition. Or is this the way I have to go?

Thank you.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption1]) {

    return [BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                             withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede != %d) AND (idTipoSede != %d)", kTipoSedePrivata, kTipoSedeDayOff]
                                                   sortKey:nil
                                             sortAscending:NO];


} if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption2]) {

    return [BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                             withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d)", kTipoSedeVenue, kTipoSedeArci, kTipoSedeSquat, kTipoSedeGalleria, kTipoSedeHouse, kTipoSedeFestival]
                                                   sortKey:nil
                                             sortAscending:NO];


} if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption3]) {

    return [BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                             withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d)", kTipoSedeVenue, kTipoSedeArci, kTipoSedeSquat, kTipoSedeGalleria, kTipoSedeHouse, kTipoSedePromoter]
                                                   sortKey:nil
                                             sortAscending:NO];
    } else {
       return [something else...];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSMutableArray` as you have to return more than one elments

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [@[] mutableCopy];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption1]) {

    [arr addObject:[BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                             withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede != %d) AND (idTipoSede != %d)", kTipoSedePrivata, kTipoSedeDayOff]
                                                   sortKey:nil
                                             sortAscending:NO]];


} 

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption2]) {

         [arr addObject:[BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                                 withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d)", kTipoSedeVenue, kTipoSedeArci, kTipoSedeSquat, kTipoSedeGalleria, kTipoSedeHouse, kTipoSedeFestival]
                                                       sortKey:nil
                                                 sortAscending:NO]];


} 

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kOption3]) {

         [arr addObject: [BOTManagedObjectContext searchObjectsForEntity:@"Sede"
                                                 withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d) OR (idTipoSede = %d)", kTipoSedeVenue, kTipoSedeArci, kTipoSedeSquat, kTipoSedeGalleria, kTipoSedeHouse, kTipoSedePromoter]
                                                       sortKey:nil
                                                 sortAscending:NO]];
 } 


 if(something else) {
                [arr addObject: [something else...]];
 }

  return arr;
```

and use where you getting this as 
 arr[0] for kOption1,arr[1] for kOption2,arr[3] for kOption3 and so on and check the array count by your need.

Comment: Fix the `if` formatting. It's formatted like there are `else if` statements but there aren't. Also, I think you want `arr addObjectsFromArray:...`.

Comment: yeah, else if was a typo. and yes it needed addObjectsFromArray.